# How to determine parameter list of callback functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, callback

In D3.js, some time I will pass a callback function as argument, e.g. In delay() below:

```
d3.select('body').selectAll('div')
  .data(distances)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .html('.')
  .style('width', '10px')
  .style('opacity', 0)
  .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 1000 })
```

Question: how do we know that the callback function shall have two parameters: d and i. And in what document does it specify 'd' should correspond to datum and 'i' correspond to index?

My question is not limited to D3.js but js convention in general. E.g. in Angular.js, I found similar thing. e.g. In the callback function passed to then() below:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

How do I know (i.e. which Document specifies ) this callback function are supposed to take an argument and this argument correspond to response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is not limited to D3.js but js convention in general.

It has to be documented by the API method that you're passing the callback to. There's no other way for you to know what arguments the callback will be called with — or when it will be called, what (if anything) it's expected to return, etc.

For your D3 example, [it's defined in the `delay` documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#delay):

> otherwise, if *delay* is a function, then the function is evaluated for each selected element (in order), being passed the current datum `d` and the current index `i`, with the `this` context as the current DOM element.

For your AngularJS example, `then` is a Promise function, [documented here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api):

> ### The Promise API
>
> ...
>
> **Methods**
>
> - `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)` – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.

Comment: I may have come across these argument. At that time I may thought they were descriptions not definition.

Comment: @modeller: Yeah, it can seem like that. And sometimes people fail to adequately document what they're going to call the callback with. :-|